# Recursive function to replace json objects

Tags: swift, function, recursion

I have this json file:

```
[
{
"person": {
  "@id": "value1",
  "name": "Mattia"
},
"person1": {
  "@ref": "value1"
},
"subPersons": [
  {
    "@id": "value2",
    "name": "Luca",
    "key": {
      "@ref": "value1"
    }
  },
  {
    "@ref": "value1"
  },
  {
    "@id": "value3",
    "subsubPersons": [
      {
        "again": {
          "@ref": "value2"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
],
"key": {
  "subKey": {
    "@ref": "value1"
  }
}
}
]
```

I need to map all objects that contains a @id so replace all @ref values with related @id values mapped. I'd like to obtain this:

```
[
{
"person": {
  "@id": "value1",
  "name": "Mattia"
},
"person1": {
  "@id": "value1",
  "name": "Mattia"
},
"subPersons": [
  {
    "@id": "value2",
    "name": "Luca",
    "key": {
      "@id": "value1",
      "name": "Mattia"
    }
  },
  {
    "@id": "value1",
    "name": "Mattia"
  },
  {
    "@id": "value3",
    "subsubPersons": [
      {
        "again": {
          "@id": "value2",
          "name": "Luca",
          "key": {
            "@id": "value1",
            "name": "Mattia"
    }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
],
"key": {
  "subKey": {
    "@id": "value1",
    "name": "Mattia"
  }
}
}
]
```

I'm using this class to replace values:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import AlamofireObjectMapper
import ObjectMapper
import SwiftyJSON
import SwiftDate
import Async

class FindAndReplace {

var ids = Dictionary<String, JSON>()
var dictChanged = Dictionary<String, JSON>()
var isDictInit: Bool = false

/*
 * Find and Replace
 */

func findAndReplace (json: JSON) -> JSON {

    findJSOGids(json)
    let replaced = replaceJSOGrefs(json, ids: ids)

    return replaced
}

/*
 * Find "@id" keys and map values related
 */

func findJSOGids (value: JSON) {

    for (key, subJson): (String, JSON) in value {

        if (key == "@id") {
            let mValueForKey = value[key].stringValue
            ids[mValueForKey] = value

        }

        if (subJson.type == Type.Dictionary || subJson.type == Type.Array) {
            findJSOGids(subJson)
        }

    }
}

/*
 * Replace "@ref" keys with fields mapped in ids
 */

func replaceJSOGrefs (var value: JSON, var ids: Dictionary<String, JSON>) -> JSON {

    if (value.type == Type.Dictionary) {

        var result = Dictionary<String, JSON> ()
        for (key, subJson): (String, JSON) in value {
            if (key == "@ref") {
                let mValueForKey = value[key].stringValue

                var isReplaced = false

                while (isReplaced == false) {

                for (idKey, _): (String, JSON) in ids[mValueForKey]! {
                    if (idKey == "@ref") {

                        print("found a @ref in dictionary")

                        let dictValueReplaced = replaceJSOGrefs(ids[mValueForKey]!, ids: ids)
                        ids.updateValue(dictValueReplaced, forKey: mValueForKey)
                    }
                }

                }

                return ids[mValueForKey]!


            } else {
                result[key] = replaceJSOGrefs(subJson, ids: ids)
            }
        }
        return JSON(result)

    } else if (value.type == Type.Array) {

        var result = [JSON]()

        for (_, subJson): (String, JSON) in value {
            result.append(replaceJSOGrefs(subJson, ids: ids))
        }

        return JSON(result)

    } else {
        return value

    }

}

}
```

It works but it misses some @ref values.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

I'm using [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) to map objects.

Comment: Are you certain that for any given dictionary "depth" where a key `@ref` exists, the key `@id` does not? Such that you don't overwrite a given key-value pair when "changing" they `@ref`-key-value pair to `@id`.

Comment: @dfri I'm 110% sure that "@id" key exists ad is unique

Answer (score 1):

I think that find-replace approach won't be as efficient since you'll have to do many passes on your data (until you can't find any `@ref` strings).

You should probably leverage the fact that your JSON models reference types semantics (as oppose to value types) and parse it as such, keeping `@ref` in the parsed objects as faulted references. Every object you parse you should add in the cache that can be referenced by `@id`. Then in the second pass you'll go through your cache rewiring each reference to using the cache you just built as a lookup table.

If every model implements following protocol

```
protocol RefObject {
    func updateReferences(using cache: [String: RefObject])
}
```

you can implement it per-model to have a custom rewiring logic per each model class. Here are few examples of such model classes:

For a wildcard represented by just `{"@ref": "xxx"}` in JSON I'd create a pointer class that would simply point to the referred object.

```
class Pointer: RefObject {
    let referredId: String
    var referred: RefObject!

    init(referedId: String) {
        self.referredId = referredId
    }

    func updateReferences(using cache: [String : RefObject]) {
        self.referred = cache[referredId]
    }
}
```

For a person you can implement something similar to

```
class Person: RefObject {
    let id: String
    let name: String

    var otherId: String?
    var other: Person?

    init(id: String, name: String, otherId: String?) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.otherId = otherId
    }

    func updateReferences(using cache: [String : RefObject]) {
        other = otherId.flatMap{ cache[$0] as? Person }
    }
}
```

(this assumes that person can have `{"id": "xx", "name": "xx", "other": {"@ref": "xx"}}` where "other" is `other` is optional

This is a general approach and not a particular implementation, but it would be very domain specific depending on your needs.

**Update** there is a similar protocol called [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org) (misleading name IMO, but it utilizes the same approach of referencing JSON objects by id). Here is an implementation in Swift: https://github.com/wvteijlingen/spine it might be worth checking it out

Comment: @I'm using [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) for that purpose, but I need to use something similar to replace json objects

Comment: as I mentioned before, I wouldn't go with approach of replacing raw objects in JSON since it will yield suboptimal performance, you might have cyclic references between objects that will cause you going though the JSON over and over again. Consider replacing or extending ObjectMapper if it doesn't fit your needs